# Need some suggestions for developing a desktop application that uses offline database

Tags: database, web-applications, electron, desktop-application, offline-mode

I have a web application that needs to be implemented as a desktop application. With my brief research about it, I came to know about **Electron**. Though it is an amazing tool to convert web applications to desktop ones, my application needs a database to run and it needs to be run offline. I also did read about using `SQLite`. I need to get more insight and suggestions as to how I should proceed with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are going to use SQLite don't to forget to encrypt the database.
To learn more about it check [this](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki)